# I am using Java and my while statement isn't working

Tags: java, do-while

If you do enter a value that isn't correct it prompts you to enter the right amount but after entering the right or wrong amount it simply ends the program. Sorry I should have mentioned earlier that the program goes on for 12 months. My problem is that once I've been prompted to enter the right amount for any given month after I've entered the wrong amount, the program takes my answer and ends, rather than taking the correct answer and moving on to the next month.

```
    System.out.print("Please enter monthly kWh usage for month 1: ");
    month1 = scan.nextInt();
    do {
          System.out.print(" Please enter a valid amount: ");
          month1 = scan.nextInt();
    } while (month1>10000 || month1<0);

    System.out.print("Please enter monthly kWh usage for month 2: ");
    month2 = scan.nextInt();
    do {
        System.out.print(" Please enter a valid amount: ");
        month2 = scan.nextInt(); 
    } while (month2>10000 || month2<0);
```

Comment: Why you use do-while to call month twice?

Comment: What are you expecting instead of "simply ending the program"?

Comment: why you have used do while and why can't you use while loop

Comment: This question made me chuckle.

Comment: I've added more detail to the question. Maybe its clearer now sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you want. The `do` is what's messing you up, because if the first input meets your condition, the loops will still occur at least once. Just use a `while` loop

```
System.out.print("Please enter monthly kWh usage for month 1: ");
month1 = scan.nextInt();

while (month1 > 10000 || month1 < 0) {
    System.out.print(" Please enter a valid amount: ");
    month1 = scan.nextInt();
}

System.out.print("Please enter monthly kWh usage for month 2: ");
month2 = scan.nextInt();

while (month2 > 10000 || month2 < 0) {
    System.out.print(" Please enter a valid amount: ");
    month2 = scan.nextInt();
}
```

**Edit: Running code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Month {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int month1;
    int month2;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter monthly kWh usage for month 1: ");
month1 = scan.nextInt();

while (month1 > 10000 || month1 < 0) {
    System.out.print(" Please enter a valid amount: ");
    month1 = scan.nextInt();
}

System.out.print("Please enter monthly kWh usage for month 2: ");
month2 = scan.nextInt();

while (month2 > 10000 || month2 < 0) {
    System.out.print(" Please enter a valid amount: ");
    month2 = scan.nextInt();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Won't this code be exactly similar to what is in the question? The do-while in the question is correct IMO.

Comment: The do-statement in the OP's question will always execute the block once. So, no matter where the value of the first input for month1 (the nextInt() outside the do-while loop) is correct or not, the nextInt() inside the block will be called again ie. the user is prompted twice.

Comment: Oh geez, the extra `nextInt` above the do while loop totally escaped me!

Comment: Cheers for that I've tried it but it still doesn't move on to the second month once I've entered the correct amount after having entered a wrong amount.

Comment: See my edit with complete running program. Works perfectly fine for me. Copy and paste my code and run it. You'll see it works just fine. I did exactly what you did, Entered wrong, entered right, for both months. Worked fine.

Comment: @user3008653 sorry the code I pasted earlier is wrong. I accidently copy and pasted you're code into my IDE. the code I originally posted doesn't work correctly, because If you input the valid amount first, it sill asks for a valid input. I reposted the correct code.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is totally correct to **"simply end the program"** because there *are* no other lines of code to execute!

The first **do while** loop will take an input and store it in the variable `month1` and then check if it is between `0` and `10000`. If so, it will go out of the loop, otherwise it will run the loop again and again till you enter the value between `0` and `10000`. Then the second loop will do the same with `month2` variable.

After storing both the variables, the program will **exit** without doing **anything**, because there are no lines of code to execute. You will need to write some lines of code after this to do something.

---

P.S. Also, it is good practice to surround the `nextInt()` with **try-catch** block because entering a non-numeric value will cause the program to crash.

---

**Edit:**

Also, you need to remove the `month1 = scan.nextInt();` and `month2 = scan.nextInt();` lines because the **do-while** loop takes care of initialising the variables for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for that but what the program does is that once you've entered the wrong value for month 1 it asks you for a valid amount (which is good) but once I've entered the right amount it simply ends and doesn't move on to month 2 (which is my dilemma).

Answer (score 0):

nextint() will throw an exception if the next characters aren't ints:

```
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
```

Try using an exception block:

```
try {
  ...
}
catch( InputMismatchException e ) {
    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when do you use do..while, you would not need to capture input outside the loop.   This force you to enter the input twice, you can remove redundant statement.

Secondly, do you have any statement to executed after second do..while?

I suggest you to provide more details what do you want to achieve here?